# Passing textbox value to label ASP.net C# jQuery UI Tabs

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, tabs

I have looked at other questions and answers and still cant seem to solve my issue.

I am using jQuery UI tabs with 3 tabs: Basic Info, Payment, Confirmation

What I want to do is pass the values on the basic information tab textbox's, and payment tab into a label that is on the confirmation tab

ASPX:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Basic Information</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">Payment Information</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3">Confirmation</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="tabs-1">
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFirstName" Text="First Name" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbFirstName" AutoPostBack="true"/>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnContinue" Text="Continue" CssClass="nexttab" />
</div>

<div id="tabs-2">
</div>

<div id="tabs-3">
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblConfirmFirstTitle" Text="First Name" />
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblConfirmFirst" />
</div>

</div>
```

Script in head:

```
$("#btnContinue").click(function () {
$("#lblConfirmFirst").html($("#tbFirstName.").val());
});
```

The next tab function works fine, and the values retain in the textbox when the next tab is selected, however it wont pass to the label on the 3rd tab.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is asp.net rename your server controls if the page has a master page.
add the attribute: ClientIDMode="Static"  to your asp controls.

Comment: <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblConfirmFirst" ClientIDMode="Static" />   <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbFirstName" AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="Static"/> Still does not send the tb value to the label on the other tab.

Answer (score 0):

> > 1. As you are using the ASP.NET controls, the ID will get changed while rendered. Use the jQuery **Ends With** selector for selecting the elements.
> > 2. Use jQuery **text** method for ASP.NET Labels (i.e. html span), and jQuery **val** method for ASP.NET Toolboxes (i.e. html input).
> > 3. Also, as the button is ASP.NET button, it gets post back every time you clickit, so use **return false;** at the end of button click method.
> > 4. You have a *AutoPostBack="true"* for textbox, which might also create problem by resetting the label text while post back.

Below code will work if *AutoPostBack="true"* is removed from textbox.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
    $("input[id$=btnContinue]").click(function () {
        $("span[id$=lblConfirmFirst]").text($("input[id$=tbFirstName]").val());
        return false;
    });
});
```